# NavigationUI navigate with fragment parameter

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

I have 3 same fragments (fragment A) and 1 fragment which showing error data (fragment B).
How i can navigate to and from fragmentB without creating 3 save actions?

Comment: So, i solved this problem using same action_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, I’ll attach the code that I managed to implement:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
    ...
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_webview">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/to_nav_error"
        app:destination="@id/nav_error" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
    ...
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_webview">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/to_nav_error"
        app:destination="@id/nav_error" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_error"
    android:name="ru.investel.client.screen.main.fragments.ErrorFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_error">
</fragment>
```

for navigation, I used:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.to_nav_error, bundle);
// to return:
navController.popBackStack();
```